# Is it possible to set the backing FS directory of a specific LXC?

Tags: disk-space-utilization, lxc, diskmanagement, partition, containers

So they don't all go to the same folder (e.g. /var/lib/lxc)?

This would let the user take advantage of other partitions/disks when the default one becomes full.

lxc version: 1.0.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use symlinks to handle this.

What operating system are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS